# I need to know how to add using an increment value up to a certain number in c++

Tags: c++, increment

I am having a hard time trying to add the starting value with the increment value up until it reaches the ending value or it cant add again because it would exceed the max value(the end value).

Ok I am just going to get straight to it, here is my assignment.

In this assignment, you will complete a C++ program that sums up the integers in a range of values and prints the result. This will be done two different ways: using a while loop and using a for loop.

For this assignment, you have more freedom in choosing the local variables that you need to declare and in figuring out what source code to write. However, your program needs to follow the coding standards of this course and fulfill the software requirements described in the next section.

Below is an example execution of the program. In this case, the program added up the numbers `8, 25, 42, 59, 76, 93, and 110`. Your program shall follow the same format shown below for prompting the user and printing the results.

Enter a starting integer value: 8

Enter an ending integer value: 121

Enter a positive increment: 17

Sum (using a while loop): 413

Sum (using a for loop): 413

Here is what I have for code so far

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  //while loop sum
  int sumw = 0;
  //for loop sum
  int sumf = 0;
  //starting integer
  int nums;
  //ending integer
  int nume;
  //increment integer
  int numi;

  cout <<"Please enter a starting value: " << endl;
  cin >> nums;
  cout <<"Please enter an ending value: " << endl;
  cin >> nume;
  cout <<"Please enter a positive increment value: " << endl;
  cin >> numi;

  if (numi <= 0 || nums > nume) cout << "Error ";
  if (numi <= 0 || nums > nume) return 0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= numi; i++){      
    sumf =+ numi;
  }
  cout << "Sum(using for loop): " << sumf;

  return 0;
}
```

If someone could help me with this that would be great!!! Thank you!!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.  What is it you need help with?

Comment: You have given us the project requirements and your code, but what are you struggling with? Please add a clear problem statement

Comment: Let me edit this real quick to let you know what i a struggling with

Comment: tl;dr: `sumf =+ numi;`  → `sumf += numi;`

Comment: Next time you ask a question spend less time on writing what the assignment is. We don't want that at all. Remember the main purpose of StackOverflow is to help users in the future solve a single problem. Since they will likely not have the same assignment.

Comment: do one thing at a time. You list >10 requirements, but what you can do next is only a single item. Forget about the rest (for now)

Comment: Sorry was just trying to let you know what i needed to do.

Comment: random offtopic advice: when you have code like this `/*while loop sum*/
int sumw = 0;` then maybe you actually wanted to write `int while_loop_sum = 0;`

Comment: As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. For specific problems with code that doesn't work as expected, you should also extract a [mcve], which also helps you focus on the problem and perhaps solve it without help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed the starting number as greater than or equal to 1(>=1).
Using while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int totalSum = 0, startingNumber, endingNumber, positiveIncrement;

  cout <<"Enter the starting number: " << endl;
  cin >> startingNumber;
  cout <<"Enter the ending number: " << endl;
  cin >> endingNumber;
  cout <<"Enter the positive increment: " << endl;
  cin >> positiveIncrement;

  if ((startingNumber <= 0) || (startingNumber > endingNumber))
  {
      cout<<"Error in input provided"<< endl;
      return 0;
  }
  totalSum = startingNumber;
  while ((startingNumber + positiveIncrement) <= endingNumber)
  {
      startingNumber += positiveIncrement;
      totalSum += startingNumber;
  }
  cout << "Total Sum = " << totalSum;
  return 0;
}
```

Using for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int totalSum = 0, startingNumber, endingNumber, positiveIncrement;

  cout <<"Enter the starting number: " << endl;
  cin >> startingNumber;
  cout <<"Enter the ending number: " << endl;
  cin >> endingNumber;
  cout <<"Enter the positive increment: " << endl;
  cin >> positiveIncrement;

  if ((startingNumber <= 0) || (startingNumber > endingNumber))
  {
      cout<<"Error in input provided"<< endl;
      return 0;
  }
  for ((totalSum = startingNumber);((startingNumber + positiveIncrement) <= endingNumber);(startingNumber += positiveIncrement))
  {
      totalSum += (startingNumber+positiveIncrement);
  }
  cout << "Total Sum = " << totalSum;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i needed for the while loop part of it!!! Thank you so much, could you help me with the for loop part as well? Because i need to do this with a while loop and a for loop

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be the same thing for a FOR loop can you help me with what i would need to do with this in a for loop?

Comment: i did, didnt get the same answer, i need to get 413 as the answer for both the while loop and the for loop. i got 413 in the while loop but not the for loop

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please find the solution using while and for loop.

Comment: as a separate code, it works but in the same code as the while loop, it gives me 110 rather than 413. I need them to work in the same code. if you could help me do that, that would be all I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Ethan you are not clear with for and while loop execution. Just try to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for

```
for (int i = nums; i <= nume; i = (i + numi)){      
  sumf += i;
}
```

Start with `nums` until you are less than or equal to `nume` and increment `i` in steps of `numi` i.e. `i = i + numi`

Additionally, you can combine:

```
if (numi <= 0 || nums > nume) cout << "Error ";
if (numi <= 0 || nums > nume) return 0;
```

to

```
if (numi <= 0 || nums > nume){
   cout << "Error ";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Shikanth thanks but do you think you could help me with the addition part of it?

Comment: Do you mean ` i = i + numi` ? The assignment question says you start with the `nums` and increment it by `numi` and add the new value. Taking the example provided starting number `8`, increment by `17` so new value is `8+17 = 25`. First time through `for` loop `sumf = 8 + 25 `. This continues till the value of `i` is less than or equal to `nume`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

See definition of `for` statement in a good reference:
`for (` *initializer*, *terminating condition*, **increment**`)`

The third parameter is the increment.

You could do something like:

```
for (int i = nums; i < nume; i = i + numi)
{
}
```

Inside the loop, you'll have figure out what you need to sum and how to do it.

Comment: Thomas thats what i am having a problem with, figuring out the insides.

Comment: You could use:  `sumf = sumf + i;`.

Comment: that is what i have down right now, i guess you arent understanding what i need to do huh? i need to add the starting value (8) and the increment value (17) all the way up until it gets to the ending value (121)

Comment: Well, think.  What is your sum variable?  Which variable is the increment?  How do you add an increment variable to a sum variable?

Comment: I am not sure how to add them, i guess i should have mentioned i am pretty new to c++. i have explored the web looking for answers just havent found one so i asked on here

Comment: To add variables:  `variable1 = variable1 + variable 2;`  This is a common idiom with many languages, dating back to at least the 1960's.

Comment: ive got that but i need it to use the increment to get a final answer of 413 and if you add these up  8, 25, 42, 59, 76, 93, and 110 you get 413. The program needs to use the increment value to get up to the ending value (121) and then add all of the number in between which would be the ones that i listed earlier

Comment: it is a very confusing program in my opinion.

Comment: The *increment* is a *variable*, which you have named as `numi`.  So, try: `sumf = sumf + numi;`.  See any patterns here?

Comment: I get 119 as the answer when i use that as the equation, what patterns am i supposed to see?

Comment: The pattern of "variable1 = variable1 + variable2" that I have had in my comments and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of operators in C++, and how to use them, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operators-c-c/ you will notice =+ is not there, becuase it is not a valid operator.
what you do have, is:

> “+=”:This operator is combination of ‘+’ and ‘=’ operators. This
> operator first adds the current value of the variable on left to the
> value on right and then assigns the result to the variable on the
> left.
>
> Example: `(a += b)` can be written as `(a = a + b)`